# How to process a command with if condition in background in command line on linux

Tags: background, command

I want to run the following command in background:

```
if [ ! -e test.txt ]; then echo test; else echo test1 && echo test2; fi;
```

I tried:

```
if [ ! -e test.txt ]; then echo test; else echo test1 && echo test2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &; fi;
```

But it gives me the error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token` ;'`
I also tried:

```
if [ ! -e test.txt ]; then echo test; else echo test1 && echo test2; fi; > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

It worked but not in the background.
Is there any method to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use:

```
 if [ ! -e test.txt ]; then echo test; else echo test1 && echo test2; fi > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

And it seems to work now

Answer (score 0):

you can make a shell script named hello.sh and run it as `./hello.sh &` hope this helps.

Comment: I know but I prefer to use only a single command.

Comment: run `if [ ! -e test.txt ]; then echo test; else echo test1 && echo test2; fi &`